# Difference between replaceCharacterInRange and stringByReplacingOccurrenceOfString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I m very confused with the string replacing methods of objective c.
Please tell where to use `ReplaceCharacterInRange` method and Where to use 
`stringByReplacingOccurrenceOfString` Method.

Answer (score 0):

These two methods differ a lot.

`replaceStringWithCharactersInRange: withString:`replaces all characters in the given range with the new string. It works on a `NSMutableString` and changes the string object you call it on.

In contrast `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` replaces all occurrences of a given string, but returns a new string object. So it does work with immutable string as well.

So you use the first method if you want to keep your string but change parts of it while you use the second when you want to replace certain substrings within the string without changing the original string.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for clearing my doubt and giving me a right direction.

Comment: Good to see it helped. for others to see that you got an helpful answer you may want to accept the answer. See also for example here http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer